# Spark submit from application running in Mesos DCOS cluster

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I have a Mesos DCOS cluster running on AWS with Spark installed via the `dcos package install spark` command. I am able to successfully execute Spark jobs using the DCOS CLI: `dcos spark run ...`

Now I would like to execute Spark jobs from a Docker container running inside the Mesos cluster, but I'm not quite sure how to reach the running instance of spark. The idea would be to have a docker container execute the `spark-submit` command to submit a job to the Spark deployment ***instead*** of executing the same job from outside the cluster with the DCOS CLI.

Current documentation seems to be focused only on running Spark via the DCOS CLI - is there any way to reach the spark deployment from another application running inside the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

DCOS IOT demo try something similar. https://github.com/amollenkopf/dcos-iot-demo

This guys run a spark docker and spark-submit in a marathon app. Check this Marathon descriptor: https://github.com/amollenkopf/dcos-iot-demo/blob/master/spatiotemporal-esri-analytics/rat01.json